# Istio multicluster cannot read certificate

Tags: istio

I'm installing Istio 1.6.5 from scratch in a multicluster environment following the docs (https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multicluster/shared/). I'm finding an error when the istio-ingressgateway component reads the CA certificate.

```
2020-08-12T13:32:46.538015Z info    Channel Connectivity change to READY
2020-08-12T13:32:46.539288Z warn    secretfetcher   failed load server cert/key pair from secret cacerts: server cert or private key is empty
2020-08-12T13:32:46.629822Z info    sds SDS gRPC server for workload UDS starts, listening on "./etc/istio/proxy/SDS"
```

The secret containing the certificates can found. However, it says it is empty. After checking the generated secret I can confirm it is correctly generated.

I am not sure if this is a problem of the current version or something has been changed and it is not correctly documented. I'm just following the guidelines in the docs and I guess the certs are correctly generated.

I would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Can You double check if the [prerequsites](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multicluster/shared/#prerequisites) for this multi cluster model were fulfilled?

Comment: Yes, the prerequisites were fulfilled. I made it work by downgrading to version 1.4.10. Somehow, this may mean that the current multicluster installation tutorial for 1.6.8 is broken.